# Finding out if the current filesystem supports symbolic links

Tags: python, windows, linux

I am making a python script that in the case of EXT filesystem, will create symbolic links of some stuff, otherwise it will move the files.

How can I know the type of the filesystem of a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some explicit code using @Joachim Isaksson's suggestion:

```
import os

try:
    os.symlink("src", "dest")
except OSError:
    print "cant do it :("
```

Answer (score 4):

What you probably should do is to just try to make the link and if it fails, copy.

It'll give you the advantage that you'll automatically support all file systems with soft links without having to do advanced detection or keeping an updated list of supported file systems.